# Mathematica: Get radius and angle of Complex number

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, complex-numbers

How to get radius (in ScientificForm or Numeric) and angle (in Degrees) of Complex number `a+jb` in one function? It could be exponential form.

Comment: see `Norm` `ArcTan` and `Degree`

Comment: I am reminded if you have v10+ there is now `AbsArg` as well.